# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec in maven project it doesn't run

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, jakarta-ee

1. my pom.xml
2. there are some dependency  and plugin that i added anyone can help me ??

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   ```

   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
       4.0.0

   ```
   <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
   <artifactId>REF</artifactId>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>war</packaging>

   <name>REF</name>

   <properties>
       <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
       <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
   </properties>



   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
   <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.1</version>
   ```

   org.hibernate
       hibernate-tools
       5.2.0.Alpha2
          
           
       org.hibernate
       hibernate-core
       3.6.3.Final

            
       org.hibernate
       hibernate
       3.2.6.ga

   ```
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
           <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
           <version>2.5.2</version>
           <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
           <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
           <version>2.5.2</version>
           <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>javax</groupId>
           <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
           <version>7.0</version>
           <type>jar</type>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>



   <build>
       <plugins>

           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>3.1</version>
               <configuration>
                   <source>1.7</source>
                   <target>1.7</target>
                   <compilerArguments>
                       <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                   </compilerArguments>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.3</version>
               <configuration>
                   <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.6</version>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <phase>validate</phase>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>copy</goal>
                       </goals>
                       <configuration>
                           <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                           <silent>true</silent>
                           <artifactItems>
                               <artifactItem>
                                   <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                   <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                   <version>7.0</version>
                                   <type>jar</type>
                               </artifactItem>
                           </artifactItems>
                       </configuration>
                   </execution>
               </executions>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>
   ```

Comment: Add the complete error message or run mvn -X ... to see all stacktraces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a plugin as a depency is wrong. If you like to execute a plugin you need to define that in an [execution block](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html)

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            ...
            <goals>
              <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <executable>maven</executable>
          <!-- optional -->
          <workingDirectory>/tmp</workingDirectory>
          <arguments>
            <argument>-X</argument>
            <argument>myproject:dist</argument>
            ...
          </arguments>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
   ...
</project>
```